# Why isn't this mongo index working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am adding the index here:

```
db.products.ensureIndex({current_features:1})
```

But then it doesn't appear to have any effect here:

```
db.products.find({"current_features" : {"$exists" : true}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 20995,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20995,
    "n" : 2,
    "millis" : 94,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for every tuple which has the specified field, mongo  use the index for this since the 2.0 version, from the doc :

> Before v2.0, $exists is not able to use an index. Indexes on other
>   fields are still used.

You should use a [sparse index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-SparseIndexes) instead. A sparse index will basically index only documents that have the indexed field. So your query will be pre-computed which ensures the maximum speed.